# How do I split subjacent lines and merge attributes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, merge, splitting

I have 2 vector line layers. They are subjacent, so one of them is exactly on top of the other but the features have different nodes and attributes.

My goal is to create labels and descriptions for the features which contain attributes from both.
The idea is to create a third layer which is split up like the two existing ones and has the attributes from both.

So I want to merge both layers and the result layer should have all the nodes and all attributes.

[image: what I am trying]

Comment: There's a small typo that changes the meaning (and possible solutions) depending on how you meant it: "one of them *ist* exactly on top of the other." Should "ist" be changed to "is" or "isn't"?

Comment: They are stacked, the have the same locations but different nodes (it's cables and pipes with different lenghts)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a label containing values from different layers in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313464/how-to-create-a-label-containing-values-from-different-layers-in-qgis). What do you think, @JGH? =)

Comment: It is the same topic but a different problem, the labelling is something I need to do if the stacking&merging doesn't work, but I need to find a solution for both

Comment: Sometimes people suggest duplicates where the question may not be a duplicate, but one of the answers is an answer to your question. Did you the virtual layer solution? IDK if you can convert a virtual layer to a permanent layer but it seems like that would totally answer your question.

Comment: Try extracting the vertices of one of the lines. Then use the `split lines at points` tool to split the other line.

Comment: Then use a spatial join to copy the attributes from the original line layer.

Answer (score 1):

Try producing a buffer around the segments of one feature. make it very small. then you will have to delete the intersection of the buffers. Afterwards cut the other feature with those buffers.

The transfer of the name information should be available as option in those tools.

Comment: yes they do only work in xy direction. but the problem you have is that lines are so thin that they will never exactly overlay. you will need a cutting feature that is bigger than a line or a point. thats why i propose generating a buffer-polygon.

Comment: It worked on some of the segements. The network of lines I am working with is very complex , does this work for intersecting lines and more than 2? I created a buffer with 0,00001 degree and didn't know which tool to use for the deletion of the intersections of the buffers.

Comment: Try vector->geoprocessing->difference